# Onsen UI Tabbarサンプルコードが動作しない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

MonacaクラウドでOnsenUIを使いnavigatorとtabbarを使ったアプリを作りたいと思っていますが、
この二つを共存させる方法がわかりません。

サンプルコードのOnsen UI Tabbarには両方が書かれているので
これを参考に勉強したいのですが、
プレビュー及びiPhoneのMonacaデバッガーで動かしてみたところ、page1.htmlのボタンを押下してもnew_page.htmlに遷移してくれません。

これは私の環境の問題なのでしょうか。あるいはコードの問題なのでしょうか。
かなり初心者的な状況でお恥ずかしいのですが、
サンプルコードが動かないという状況に軽い絶望を感じております。

目的はnavigatorとtabbarの共存方法を知ることなので、
他に良いサンプルがあるという情報でも助かります。
ナビゲーションはnavigatorだけで充分、tabbarは常時表示されるUIとして使いたいと思っています。

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

確かに動きませんね・・・。
page1.htmlの下記の部分を

```
<ons-button 
    ng-click="ons.navigator.pushPage('new_page.html')">
    Push New Page
</ons-button>
```

こんな感じに変えると動きます。

```
<ons-button 
    ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('new_page.html')">
    Push New Page
</ons-button>
```

また、new_page.htmlの「Pop Page」もこんな感じに変えると動きます。

```
<ons-button ng-click="myNavigator.popPage();">
    Pop Page
</ons-button>
```

ちなみ`myNavigator`はnavigator.htmlの`var=`の部分です。

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">
```